# HTML anchor with name attribute in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, anchor

I'd like to make anchors to every post in my asp.net forum. Every forum's post is rendered using repeater control. How can I render `<a name="anchor_name"></a>` in asp.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a name='<%# Eval("PostId") %>' />
```

where PostId is the name of the property you want to appear in your anchor.

Comment: This PostId is known only in PostsRepeater_ItemDataBound event method so how should I reference it?

Answer (score 1):

This won't be exact code as I'm not in VS to ensure the syntax but something like this should get you were you want to go.

```
<a name="<%# Bind('PostId') %>" runat="server" />
```

Comment: You don't need two-way binding here.  Eval is sufficient.

Comment: I thought about that after I submitted.  You shouldn't need runat either, but I tend to use both when testing and then remove what it didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink class, and override UniqueID property to return the actual ID:

```
override string UniqueID { get { return ID; }  }
```

Use this new user control in the item template of the repeater.

```
<MyPrefix:MyHyperLink ID="IDOfYourHyperLink" ... />
```

On ItemDataBound do:

```
(e.Item.FindControl("IDOfYourHyperLink") as MyHyperlink).ID = NowIKnowWhatToUseHere;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've resolved it this way:

```
<a name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' />
```

where Id is the property of binded entity.

Comment: Travis's Eval("Id") is equivalent - it just automatically picks up the Container.DataItem.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `<a name="anchor_name"></a>` in the ItemTempate of the repeater at the appropriate spot should do the trick.  A little more information might help.

Comment: Well of course you're going to put the ID in the name attribute!  I don't get why I get a -1.  We were given NO information.